# Как сделать многофункциональную форму на jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Делаю простенькое CRUD веб-приложение на Spring MVC. Есть список пользователей. В список можно добавить нового пользователя, также можно взять существующего пользователя из списка и отредактировать его данные. Эти оба действия хочу делать в одной форме. 
Изначально форма пустая, в неё можно занести данные и добавить нового пользователя. Если же возле существующего пользователя нажимается кнопка "редактировать", то в форму нужно перенести данные этого пользователя и позволить их отредактировать. После редактирования, форма очищается и её снова можно использовать для добавления новых людей. 
Приложение всего на одну страничку, поэтому jsp, как мне показалось, освоить проще всего для такой цели. Вот только на этом моменте застрял, прошу помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**form.jsp**

```
<form:form action="/users" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <label for="firstName">Имя</label>
    <form:input type="text" path="firstName" id="firstName" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/create", "/{userId}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userForm(@PathVariable Optional<String> userId) {
        User user;
        if (userId.isPresent())
            user = userRepository.findOne(userId.get());
        else
            user = new User();
        return new ModelAndView("form" , "user", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:/some-success-url";
    }
}
```

По ссылке `/users/create` будет открываться пустая форма для создания нового пользователя, а по `/users/1`, например, заполненная данными пользователя с идентификатором 1.